# Kendals tau-b correlation with lots of 0 variance columns

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, ranking, kendall-tau

I am writing a paper that is meant to establish that certain algorithms rank candidate values accross multiple problems in a different way. To do this, I take Algorithm A and run it on the candidate values and do the same for candidate B. When I run them, I notice that for multiple problems they rank the values as follows:

```
     A     B

c1   1     1
c2   2     1
c3   3     1
```

Is there a metric that can tell me something about how simillar these 2 ranking sets are without saying the correlation is undefined.
fyi. I've tried Kendall's tau and it is undefined for the example given and so therefore I am looking for a metric that can tell me something useful in this particular case.

Comment: Do you have a true ranking to which you can compare or are you more concerned with how different the rankings are apart from a known measure of accuracy?

Comment: I am more concerned with how different the rankings are.

Comment: Can your provide some pseudo-data. I am not sure I understand what a 0 column represents. Is Tau-b = 0 or all predictors zero for either or both of the candidate values?

Comment: Edited and added an example. A 0 variance column is one where all the candidates are tied eg. the B column on the example given.

Comment: I don’t know that there is a fix for this scenario. Can you calculate the index using something other than whole integers?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It's a metric called Wilsons e by Wilson(1970). See [Gonzalez et al. (1996)](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~gonzo/papers/gamma.pdf) for details

Bibtex below:

```
@article{gonzalez1996measuring,
  title={Measuring ordinal association in situations that contain tied scores.},
  author={Gonzalez, Richard and Nelson, Thomas O},
  journal={Psychological bulletin},
  volume={119},
  number={1},
  pages={159},
  year={1996},
  publisher={American Psychological Association}
}
```